# C# WPF Binding параметров

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, style, usercontrol

Есть UserControl:

```
<ProgressBar x:Class="Black_Tunnel.UI.RoundProgressBar"
             x:Name="ProgresBar"
....

<ProgressBar.Style>
<Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
....


<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
....

<ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
....

<Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stretch="Uniform"
                          Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
....
```

Тут значение Fill подхватывает "Red" через {TemplateBinding Background}
А Stroke "2" (или что то другое) через {TemplateBinding BorderBrush} не подхватывает.

Не пойму что я не так делаю. Прописать значение Stroke в ручную можно, а связать не получается.

Comment: А в студийном логе после того, как ты запускаешь приложение, ошибок биндинга нету?

Comment: "Ошибки" есть, но компиляция проходит успешно. (пользуюсь решарпером, как я понял он тоже ошибки свои выводит) В запущенном приложении компонент не подхватывает значение. (в данном случае не меняет толщину обводки)

Comment: ... Остается дефолтной пока не заменишь биндинг явным приравниванием.

Comment: Ошибки биндинга не являются критичнымы для запуска приложения. Они ж на слабой связанности построены. Потому в первую очередь побори их всех, быть не должно и скорее всего выплывешь к причине "промаха".